Do we have a canonical question for "How to sell bitcoins?"?
After encountering yet another question about "How to sell bitcoins for fiat?" today (what things may I need to start withdrawal of bitcoins), I was looking for a canonical question akin to the corresponding 
How do you obtain bitcoins? on side of "How do you buy bitcoins?". It seems strange that we don't have a canonical question for that yet.
I found:

How do I convert Bitcoin to cash at my bank via Mt. Gox?
Good way to sell Bitcoins online?
How can I sell bitcoins and transfer the funds to bank my account?
How to sell bitcoins for cash? 
How can I withdraw my bitcoins from my blockchain wallet and convert them into cash?
Sell bitcoin for 0% fee
Do all Banks and Credit Unions in the U.S. accept Bitcoin?
Buying bitcoin is easy, but how do you get it back?

And about 70 unanswered, or closed as duplicate questions.
Am I missing a question that is more popular and has a great answer to that question? Otherwise, I'd suggest that we'd polish and promote the third (emphasized) question to consolidate all the answers of the duplicates there.

Since I didn't get any feedback in ten days, I went ahead and merged a few questions into the proposed. I've linked a few more, so that the proposed canonical question should be very easy to find.
I would appreciate if more people take a look at the question in order to help prioritize the useful answers and/or provide additional answers.

How can I sell bitcoins and transfer the funds to bank my account?

